# how to create session and check nullreference in another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i have a task of Creating a session variable and have to check nullreference of my session variable in another page.here is my code

```
 if (RetValue == false)
 {
    takeTestAnchor.HRef = "SubscriptionInformation.aspx?sid="+subscriptionid 
                          + "&uid=" + _myUser.UserId;
    takeTestAnchor.Attributes.Add("class", "subscribeframe");

else    
{    
     if(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["tid"]) != string.Empty)
     {    
          takeTestAnchor.HRef = "testinstruction.aspx?tid=" + Convert.ToString(ID) 
                               + "&AT=" + assestype;
          takeTestAnchor.Attributes.Add("class", "testframe");
     }
}
```

here i have to create a session variable for storing **tid** and **AT** before sending to SubscriptionInformation.aspx
if condition returns false. and this session variable have to use after going to SubscriptionInformation.aspx 
and there after ccavenue and to success page..
In success page there is a button **GotoTest**..
when user clicks, this session variable should check null reference..
if it is null have to navigate to login page.

**so my effort is to make session variable is**

```
if (Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["tid"]) != string.Empty)
{
     **Session["TakeAtest"] = Convert.ToString(ID) + "," + assestype;**
     takeTestAnchor.HRef = "testinstruction.aspx?tid=" + Convert.ToString(ID) 
                           + "&AT=" + assestype;
     takeTestAnchor.Attributes.Add("class", "testframe");
}
```

here i am created the session variable with 2 values separated by comma.My doubt is is this correct way of creating session variable???? and 
i have written  in successpage.aspx is

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
 {
      if( Session["TakeAtest"]!=null)
      {
         string _test=Convert.ToString(Session["TakeAtest"]);
         string[] _takeatest= _test.Split(','); 
         string tid= _takeatest[0];  
         string AT=_takeatest[1];
         Response.Redirect("testinstruction.aspx?tid=" + tid + "&AT=" + AT);
      }
```

My doubt is..is Session which i created is can check here or not?? or my session creation is wrong? i can check this by putting debugger..but here this process have to work after ccavenue..so i can't check this..i can only check this in server only.am i correct in session creation ?? and am i correct in calling session for null reference??

Comment: Could you please edit your post and format code so it looks like code? (I've tried, but it seem to be missing some curly braces, so not sure how to fix that).

Comment: hi ALExEI..Is it ok now??

Comment: Here what i am trying to do is if enduser selects a test it redirects to ccavenue page and after payment goes success then i have to retun back to test..so that i am putting testid and testtype in session and if session not null redirecting to test..

Comment: You are correct in how you create a session variable, and also correct to check that it is not null before attempting to get the value. You may wish to remove the variable too, using `Session.Remove("TakeAtest")`, when you are finished with it and don't want it to be accessed again. Why store two values in one Session variable instead of just creating two Session variables?

Answer (score 0):

All your code is correct in setting the session value and retrieving the value and checking if it is null..

But Time taken for splitting and merging strings will be more while comparing with creating of two sessions. For the performance measuring, consider creating two sessions and check for null by converting to a string..

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["name1"])) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["name2"])))
{
   //do if true
}
else
{
   Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx",true);
}
```